# Kantu testing automation Select button

Tags: selenium, kantu

I have an issue with Kantu Select button on both Firefox and Chrome on Mac When I press the Select button to get the object locator on the page I see the Kantu icon with "yellow S" that means that Kantu in Select mode. However, when I click on any object in the page; it doesn't select anything. I accedntially opened a new tab and found that the Select is working on the new opened tab, instead of the required first tab.
Any help please?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, in Mac the yellow select tag on the Kantu icon that appears when pressing the Select button don't disappear even if I close Kantu and reopen it again.